# Data-model symbols in Latex

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I want to add the following symbols to show the connection between some data-models in `.tex` document, I was wondering to know whether we have any predefined code (latex of Unicode) for them, or I have to use pictures.

[image]

Comment: See `arws.meta` library in TIkZ package,

Comment: Should the symbols be that long?

Comment: @egreg , not actually,  I just need the right sides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proposal:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ljoinrel}[1]{\mathrel{\mspace{-#1mu}}}
\newcommand{\negljoinrel}[1]{\mathrel{\mspace{#1mu}}}

\newcommand{\One}{%
  \relbar\ljoinrel{4}\relbar\ljoinrel{4}\relbar
  \ljoinrel{14}\mapstochar\negljoinrel{14}%
}
\newcommand{\Many}{%
  \relbar\ljoinrel{4}\relbar\ljoinrel{4}\relbar
  \ljoinrel{14}<%
}
\newcommand{\Oone}{%
  \relbar\ljoinrel{7}\relbar\ljoinrel{7}\relbar\ljoinrel{6}\relbar
  \ljoinrel{14}\mapstochar\negljoinrel{6}\mapstochar\negljoinrel{6}%
}
\newcommand{\Onemany}{%
  \relbar\ljoinrel{4}\relbar\ljoinrel{4}\relbar
  \ljoinrel{14}\mapstochar<%
}
\newcommand{\Zeroone}{%
  \relbar\ljoinrel{11}\relbar\joinrel
  \mathrel{\circ}\joinrel
  \relbar\ljoinrel{8}\mapstochar\negljoinrel{8}%
}
\newcommand{\Zeromany}{%
  \relbar\ljoinrel{11}\relbar\joinrel
  \mathrel{\circ}\joinrel
  \relbar\ljoinrel{14}<%
}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{$\One$}\showthe\wd0
\sbox0{$\Many$}\showthe\wd0
\sbox0{$\Oone$}\showthe\wd0
\sbox0{$\Onemany$}\showthe\wd0
\sbox0{$\Zeroone$}\showthe\wd0
\sbox0{$\Zeromany$}\showthe\wd0

$A \One B$

$A \Many B$

$A \Oone B$

$A \Onemany B$

$A \Zeroone B$

$A \Zeromany B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are awesome